# What is the most pythonic way to sort dates sequences?

Tags: python, algorithm, python-2.7, sequence

I have a list of stings representing a month in a year (not sorted and not consecutive):
`['1/2013', '7/2013', '2/2013', '3/2013', '4/2014',  '12/2013', '10/2013', '11/2013', '1/2014', '2/2014']`

I'm looking for a Pythonic way to sort all of them and separate each consecutive sequence as the following suggests:

```
[ ['1/2013', '2/2013', '3/2013', '4/2013'], 
  ['7/2013'], 
  ['10/2013', '11/2013', '12/2013', '1/2014', '2/2014'] 
]
```

Any ideas?

Comment: how they are grouped, in consecutive months?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on [the example from the docs that shows how to find runs of consecutive numbers](https://docs.python.org/2.6/library/itertools.html#examples) using [`itertools.groupby()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby):

```
from itertools import groupby
from pprint import pprint

def month_number(date):
    month, year = date.split('/')
    return int(year) * 12 + int(month)

L = [[date for _, date in run]
     for _, run in groupby(enumerate(sorted(months, key=month_number)),
                           key=lambda (i, date): (i - month_number(date)))]
pprint(L)
```

*The key to the solution is differencing with a range generated by `enumerate()` so that consecutive months all appear in same group (run).*

#### Output

```
[['1/2013', '2/2013', '3/2013'],
 ['7/2013'],
 ['10/2013', '11/2013', '12/2013', '1/2014', '2/2014'],
 ['4/2014']]
```

Comment: `months` is not defined?

Comment: @RedBaron: `months` is the original list from the question.

Comment: While the shortest, this solution does not look like extremely idiomatic Python, though a Haskell or F# fan would appreciate it :) It can be slightly simplified by casting the dates as number of months: http://pastebin.com/8KR8Ayzc

Comment: @9000: using number of months is definitely an improvement. I've updated the answer

Answer (score 2):

The groupby examples are cute, but too dense and will break on this input: `['1/2013', '2/2017']`, i.e. when there are adjacent months from non-adjacent years.

```
from datetime import datetime
from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta

def areAdjacent(old, new):
    return old + relativedelta(months=1) == new

def parseDate(s):
    return datetime.strptime(s, '%m/%Y')

def generateGroups(seq):
    group = []
    last = None
    for (current, formatted) in sorted((parseDate(s), s) for s in seq):
        if group and last is not None and not areAdjacent(last, current):
            yield group
            group = []
        group.append(formatted)
        last = current
    if group:
        yield group
```

Result:

```
[['1/2013', '2/2013', '3/2013'], 
 ['7/2013'],
 ['10/2013', '11/2013', '12/2013', '1/2014', '2/2014'],
 ['4/2014']]
```

Answer (score 1):

If you wants to just sort your list then use sorted function and pass `key`  value = a function that converts date-string into Python's `datetime` object as `lambda d: datetime.strptime(d, '%m/%Y')`, check following code example for your list as **`L`**:

```
>>> from datetime import datetime
>>> sorted(L, key = lambda d: datetime.strptime(d, '%m/%Y'))
['1/2013', '2/2013', '3/2013', '7/2013', '10/2013', 
 '11/2013', '12/2013', '1/2014', '2/2014', '4/2014'] # indented by hand
```

To split "list of month/year strings" into "list of list of consecutive months", you can use following script (read comments), In which, first I  sorted the list `L` then groups strings on the basis of consecutive month (to check consecutive month I written a function):

```
def is_cm(d1, d2):
    """ is consecutive month pair?
        : Assumption d1 is older day's date than d2
    """
    d1 = datetime.strptime(d1, '%m/%Y')
    d2 = datetime.strptime(d2, '%m/%Y') 

    y1, y2 = d1.year, d2.year
    m1, m2 = d1.month, d2.month

    if y1 == y2: # if years are same d2 should be in next month
        return (m2 - m1) == 1
    elif (y2 - y1) == 1: # if years are consecutive
        return (m1 == 12 and m2 == 1)
```

It works as follows:

```
>>> is_cm('1/2012', '2/2012')
True # yes, consecutive
>>> is_cm('12/2012', '1/2013')
True # yes, consecutive
>>> is_cm('1/2015', '12/2012') # None --> # not consecutive
>>> is_cm('12/2012', '2/2013')
False # not consecutive
```

Code to split your code:

```
def result(dl):
    """
    dl: dates list - a iterator of 'month/year' strings
    type: list of strings

    returns: list of lists of strings
    """
    #Sort list:
    s_dl = sorted(dl, key=lambda d: datetime.strptime(d, '%m/%Y'))
    r_dl = [] # list to be return
    # split list into list of lists
    t_dl = [s_dl[0]] # temp list
    for d in s_dl[1:]:
        if not is_cm(t_dl[-1], d): # check if months are not consecutive
            r_dl.append(t_dl)
            t_dl = [d]
        else:
            t_dl.append(d)
    return r_dl

result(L)
```

Don't forget to include `from datetime import datetime`, This trick I believe you can easily update for a new list of dates in which dates are in other format.

After @[9000](https://stackoverflow.com/users/223424/9000) hint I could simplified my sorted function and removed old answer if you wants to check old script check @[codepad](http://codepad.org/5dFKXnKk).

Comment: Adding a link of script that makes final nested list @[codepad](http://codepad.org/DfMSAv32)

Comment: If you stopped thinking about the pairs of numbers as of dates, you could simplify your solution :)

Comment: @9000 Thanks If you have further suggestion please help me to improve my answer.

Answer (score 0):

An easy solution in this specific case (not many elements) is just to iterate over all the months:

```
year = dates[0].split('/')[1]
result = []
current = []
for i in range(1, 13):
    x = "%i/%s" % (i, year)
    if x in dates:
        current.append(x)
        if len(current) == 1:
            result.append(current)
    else:
        current = []
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, here's one without itertools and as short as I could make it without hurting readability. The trick is in use of `zip`. It's basically @moe's answer unwrapped a bit.

```
def parseAsPair(piece):
  """Transforms things like '7/2014' into (2014, 7) """
  m, y = piece.split('/')
  return (int(y), int(m))

def goesAfter(earlier, later):
  """Returns True iff earlier goes right after later."""
  earlier_y, earlier_m = earlier
  later_y, later_m = later
  if earlier_y == later_y:  # same year?
    return later_m == earlier_m + 1 # next month
  else: # next year? must be Dec -> Jan
    return later_y == earlier_y + 1 and earlier_m == 12 and later_m == 1

def groupSequentially(months):
  result = []  # final result
  if months:
    sorted_months = sorted(months, key=parseAsPair)
    span = [sorted_months[0]]  # current span; has at least the first month
    for earlier, later in zip(sorted_months, sorted_months[1:]):
      if not goesAfter(parseAsPair(earlier), parseAsPair(later)):
        # current span is over
        result.append(span)
        span = []
      span.append(later)
    # last span was not appended because sequence ended without breaking
    result.append(span)
  return result
```

Trying it:

```
months =['1/2013', '7/2013', '2/2013', '3/2013', '4/2014', '12/2013',
         '10/2013', '11/2013', '1/2014', '2/2014']

print groupSequentially(months)  # output wrapped manually

[['1/2013', '2/2013', '3/2013'], 
 ['7/2013'], 
 ['10/2013', '11/2013', '12/2013', '1/2014', '2/2014'], 
 ['4/2014']]
```

We could save a bit of performance and cognitive load if we mapped `parseAsPair` over the list in the very end. Then every invocation of `parseAsPair` could be removed from `groupSequentially`, but we'd have to transform the result to strings again.