# Pythonic: Find all consecutive sub-sequences of certain length

Tags: python, algorithm, list

I have a list of integers and I want to find all consecutive sub-sequences of length n in this list. For example:

```
>>> int_list = [1,4,6,7,8,9]
>>> conseq_sequences(int_list, length=3)
[[6,7,8], [7,8,9]]
```

The best I could come up with is:

```
def conseq_sequences(self, li, length):
    return [li[n:n+length]
            for n in xrange(len(li)-length+1)
            if li[n:n+length] == range(li[n], li[n]+length)]
```

This isn't overly readable. Is there any readable pythonic way of doing this?

Comment: You can assume int_list being ordered.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a more general solution that works for arbitrary input iterables (not just sequences):

```
from itertools import groupby, islice, tee
from operator import itemgetter

def consecutive_subseq(iterable, length):
    for _, consec_run in groupby(enumerate(iterable), lambda x: x[0] - x[1]):
        k_wise = tee(map(itemgetter(1), consec_run), length)
        for n, it in enumerate(k_wise):
            next(islice(it, n, n), None) # consume n items from it
        yield from zip(*k_wise)
```

- [`itertools.groupby`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) finds consecutive substrings such as `6, 7, 8, 9` in the input. It is based on [the example from the docs that shows how to find runs of consecutive numbers](https://docs.python.org/2.6/library/itertools.html#examples):

  > The key to the solution is differencing with a range generated by
  >   enumerate() so that consecutive integers all appear in same group
  >   (run).
- [`itertools.tee`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.tee) + `zip` allow to iterate over the substring k-wise -- a generalization of [`pairwise` recipe from the `itertools` docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools-recipes).
- `next(islice(iterator, n, n), None)` is from [the `consume` recipe there](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools-recipes).

Example:

```
print(*consecutive_subseq([1,4,6,7,8,9], 3))
# -> (6, 7, 8) (7, 8, 9)
```

The code uses Python 3 syntax that could be adapted for Python 2 if needed.

See also, [What is the most pythonic way to sort dates sequences?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23075453/4279)

Comment: Looks most elegant to me in terms of using built-in libraries. Will have to look up the links you provided in order to completely get what's happening. Readability is still pretty tough, though!

Answer (score 1):

One solution could be as follows:

```
import numpy # used diff function from numpy, but if not present, than some lambda or other helper function could be used. 

def conseq_sequences(li, length):
    return [int_list[i:i+length] for i in range(0, len(int_list)) if sum(numpy.diff(int_list[i:i+length]))==length-1]
```

Basically, first, I get consecutive sub-lists of given length from the list, and then check if the sum of the differences of their elements is equal to `length - 1`.

Please not that if elements are consecutive, their difference will add up to `length - 1`, e.g. for sub-list `[5,6,7]` the difference of its elements is `[1, 1]` and sum of it is `2`.

But to be honest not sure if this solution is clearer or more pythonic than yours.

Just in case you don't have `numpy`, the `diff` function can be easly defined as follows:

```
def diff(l):
  '''For example, when l=[1,2,3] than return is [1,1]'''  
  return [x - l[i - 1] for i, x in enumerate(l)][1:]
```

Answer (score 0):

Using [operator.itemgetter](https://docs.python.org/2/library/operator.html#operator.itemgetter)  and [itertools.groupby](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby)

```
 def conseq_sequences(li, length):
    res = zip(*(li[i:] for i in xrange(length)))
    final = []
    for x in res:
        for k, g in groupby(enumerate(x), lambda (i, x): i - x):
            get_map = map(itemgetter(1), g)
            if len(get_map) == length:
                final.append(get_map)
    return final
```

Without imports.

```
def conseq_sequences(li, length):
    res = zip(*(li[i:] for i in xrange(length)))
    final = []
    for ele in res:
        if all(x == y+1 for x, y in zip(ele[1:], ele)):
            final.append(ele)
    return final
```

Which can be turned into list comprehension:

```
def conseq_sequences(li, length):
    res = zip(*(li[i:] for i in xrange(length)))
    return [ ele for ele in res if all(x == y+1 for x, y in zip(ele[1:], ele))]
```

Comment: This behaves differently from the OP's code on inputs like `[4, 1, 5, 2, 6]`.

Comment: @user2357112, temporarily brain dead, I completely overlooked the consecutive part.

Answer (score 0):

```
 def condition (tup):
    if tup[0] + 1 == tup[1] and tup[1] + 1 == tup[2] :
        return True
    return False

 def conseq_sequence(li):
   return [x for x in map(None, iter(li), iter(li[1:]), iter(li[2:])) if condition(x)]
```

Comment: This doesnt  respect the consecutiveness-constraint: `conseq_sequence([1,4,2,7,3])` gives as result `[[1, 2, 3], [2, 3, 4]]`. However the list `[1,2,3]` isn't a sublist of our intial list and as for `[2,3,4]` the number appear in a different order in the initial list and aren't consequitive either.

Comment: Sorry, i forgot about that condition. Now the code also takes care of that condition

Comment: I have made an assumption that the list's length will be greater than 3, that can be checked easily